# Include items with zero count using pandas size() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe consisting of some Jira issues which I'm trying to sort by week and status, and get the amount of items for each status per week. So for example, two weeks of my dataframe currently look like this:

```
2019-11-04     Authorize Work      4
               Await Work          1
               Check Work          4
               Closed              4
               Confirm Work        3
               Do Work             3
2019-11-11     Authorize Work      6
               Do Work             2
```

I've gotten to this point with the following:

```
# Remove the time portion of the date
df['creation_date'] = df['creation_date'].dt.date
# Set the date to be a week long delta
df['creation_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_date']) - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
# Sort together by creation date within the week and the status, and do a count
endf = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="creation_date", freq="W-MON"), "status"]).size()
```

You'll notice that the second week only has two statuses, where the first has six. This is because there were zero jira issues with the missing statuses during the second week. Is there a way to make the size function include the missing statuses with a count of zero, so that the data within each week is the same set of statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `unstack` and `stack`:

```
enddf.unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0).stack()
```

Output:

```
                           2
0          1                
2019-11-04 Authorize Work  4
           Await Work      1
           Check Work      4
           Closed          4
           Confirm Work    3
           Do Work         3
2019-11-11 Authorize Work  6
           Await Work      0
           Check Work      0
           Closed          0
           Confirm Work    0
           Do Work         2
```

Comment: You're my hero right now, this worked perfectly. Thank you!